# How to define a friend function in another module?

Tags: c++, module, friend

I have:

```cpp
export module A;

class A;

export class B {
public:
    void b(A a);
};

export class A {
    friend void B::b(A a);
};

void B::b(A a){}
```

How can I define B in another module?

I tried:

```cpp
export module A;

import B;

export class A {
    friend void B::b(A a);
};
```

```cpp
export module B;

class A;

export class B {
public:
    void b(A a);
};

import A;

void B::b(A a){}
```

But now there's a circular dependency between the two module units because they import each other